Load livewire component on timeout
Needs to load livewire component on timeout
Here is my livewire call code:
<livewire:data-list data="{{$id}}"/>

But i want to load this component after some time like seconds...
Here is livewire handle:
class DataList extends Component
{
    public $id;

    public function render()
    {
        $data = [Third party call for data.....];
        return view('livewire.data-list', [
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }
}

But i don't know how can i handle timeout so i can get data on specific time.

This is a possible solution:
Container component
class TimeoutContainer extends Component
{
    public $showContent = false;
}

Container view
<div x-init="setTimeout(() => {$wire.set('showContent', true)}, 2000)">
    <livewire:data-list data="{{$id}}" :showData="$showContent" />
</div>

Subcomponent
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Reactive;


class DataList extends Component
{
    public $id;

    #[Reactive]
    public $showData = false;


    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->showData) {

            $data = [Third party call for data.....];

            return view('livewire.data-list', [
                'data' => $data,
            ]);
        }

        return '<div>no data yet</div>';
    }
}

The delay is managed by the Alpine x-init="setTimeout(().... which causes the update of the $showContent property in the container component.
When the child componet is initially rendered it shows the empty content because the $showData property is set to false
Since the $showData of the child component depends on the $showContent property and it is set as #[Reactive], when the time runs out the child component is redrawn loading the data and showing the view.

Another solution using events:
Container view
<div x-init="setTimeout(() => {$dispatch('showTheData')}, 2000)">
    <livewire:data-list data="{{$id}}" />
</div>

Subcomponent
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;


class Timeout extends Component
{
    public $id;
    public $showData = false;


    #[On('showTheData')]
    public function showTheData()
    {
        $this->showData = true;
    }


    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->showData) {

            $data = [Third party call for data.....];

            return view('livewire.data-list', [
                'data' => $data,
            ]);
        }

        return '<div>no data yet</div>';
    }
}

In this solution the container view dispatches an event when the time runs out. The event is catched by the showTheData() method of the child component, this method changes the $showData property and causes the re-rendering of the view.
The render() method of the child component works the same as the one in the previous solution
